# Trying to delete Account Name on Case, keeps pulling in Contact's Account

Tags: email2case

I'm trying to delete the Account Name from a number of cases as it is incorrect.  However, the Contact Name field is filled in (and we want to keep that contact) which automatically pulls in the Contact's Account into the Account Name field.

So I delete the Account Name, save, and then it magically reappears.

Any good way to get around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be to create a generic account that you could associate the case with. You can select an account different from the account on the contact but you cannot leave it null. See [docs](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_case.htm) here.

[image]